# Not able to display cells in tableview. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a link to a gist file to my code.  The first one is of the ViewController.  I included the code to my Cell Controller and Data Model.

I'm not sure what's going wrong with my code, and why I'm unable to display my cells in my simulator.

https://gist.github.com/baruma/33ceb1afdab08a8d47c24635753460d6

Comment: Your code does not show where you are getting any data for your `boardPost` array. If it has no data, you won't see any rows.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues here:

1. you are missing the registration of your cell. just add:
   `messageBoardTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MessageBoardPostCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessageBoardPostCell")`
2. You are missing the data. initialise your `boardPost` array with some fake data to test it.

Comment: 1. registration for my cell?  I've never heard of this but okay I'll try it out!  Where would I add this line of code?
2. Got it, I tried creating fake data in the viewdidload but I get this error message : Value of type '[MessageBoardPosts]' has no member 'title' (assuming i tried adjusting the title property)

Comment: viewDidLoad or anywhere else before setting the tableView datasource